# The use of master theorem appriopriately

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recurrence-relation, recursion, master-theorem

I have a recurrence relation and trying to use master theorem to solve it. The recurrence relation is:

$T(n) = 3T(n/5) + n^{0.5}$

Can I use the master theorem in that relation? If so, can I say that $T(n)$ is $Θ(n^{0.5})$?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own, we have litte to
work with. Let me direct you towards our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!

Comment: Also, check out the many questions concerning the [tag:master-theorem].